# why does helm do not accept kubernetes secrets for deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

i have created secret inside Kubernetes cluster for image pull from private repository and added it to helm values.yml.

after deployment start (`helm install chart /chart`) i see that helm deployment is crashing all the time by timeout.

"kubectl describe pod" shows me an error: "imagePullBackoff" and "wrong credentials".

at the same time if to deploy the same app with `kubectl apply -f deployment.yml` file this secret works as expected and image is downloaded without any issues and deployment is successful.

the question is how to force this secret to work with helm charts?

Comment: Could you please show your helm values file and template file? And did you compare your deployment.yaml with helm rendered yaml file to see any differences?

Comment: sorry, i am still a newbuy with helm. i have only added a secret`s name (created through "kubect create secret") to helm in values.yaml file that it could be able to pull the image. no any template were created for this by me. but as i see helm does not work with this. should i also create a secret in helm format?

Comment: Where is this private repo? How exactly have you added the secret, can you show the whole command without private data? Can you paste the values.yaml?

Comment: repo is in azure container registry. values.yml looks like that https://jumpshare.com/v/tbOMLOxQCEJA1z1FuIOQ

Comment: 2024: got still the same problem with helm and Openshift.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating secret using this command:

```
kubectl  create secret docker-registry mysecret --docker-server=<docker-repo> --docker-username=<docker-username> --docker-password=<docker-password> --docker-email=<email>
```

(Provide your respective inputs in the above command)

Comment: I did it at the beginning

Answer (score -1):

From helm document

First, assume that the credentials are defined in the values.yaml file like so:

```
imageCredentials:
  registry: quay.io
  username: someone
  password: sillyness
```

We then define our helper template as follows:

```
{{- define "imagePullSecret" }}
{{- printf "{\"auths\": {\"%s\": {\"auth\": \"%s\"}}}" .Values.imageCredentials.registry (printf "%s:%s" .Values.imageCredentials.username .Values.imageCredentials.password | b64enc) | b64enc }}
{{- end }}
```

Finally, we use the helper template in a larger template to create the Secret manifest:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: myregistrykey
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ template "imagePullSecret" . }}
```

In deployment

```
  containers:
  - name: private-reg-container
    image: <your-private-image>
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: myregistrykey
```

Comment: I don't think putting a secret in values.yaml file is a good way to go. Where are you going to store your values file? Version control or cloud storage? It's a security concern here.

Comment: Also the OP is asking that he is using a K8s secret. So your answer is out of the context.

Comment: of course i could use login and password, but i already have a secret created for this. and solution of Suresh is little bit complicated for me. i am looking for something easier where i do not need to store credentials in file in repository. create a secret in k8s is very simple. i do not understand why create a secret in helm is so much complicated and it does not accept it although it works with other k8s objects!